# is it possible to mimic or ghost a table?

Tags: mysql

So the situation is that I have some code that uses a database table and I think I can replace that table with a view from another table.

Potentially I would rename/remove the existing table and then somehow create a view that replicates the table so that the php code thinks it is working with the table.

Perhaps what I should do is create the view and then simply find and replace all instances of the table name in the code?

What is the best way to mimic or ghost a table?

Comment: delete the table, create a view with the same name as the old table?  only problem with this is if anything wants to insert into view. you wont be able to

Comment: @pala_ Under certain conditions he will. Read more about it in my answer.

Comment: @fancyPants news to me, but by the list of exclusions it's almost always non-updateable heh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the table with

```
 RENAME TABLE <table_name> TO <new_table_name>;
```

Then create the view with the same name as the original table_name. Your PHP code will continue to work fine without further ado when it's reading from the table. If your code also has to update, delete or insert into that view, there are certain restrictions.

> There must be a one-to-one relationship between the rows in the view
>   and the rows in the underlying table. There are also certain other
>   constructs that make a view nonupdatable. To be more specific, a view
>   is not updatable if it contains any of the following:
>
> - Aggregate functions (SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), COUNT(), and so forth)
> - DISTINCT
> - GROUP BY
> - HAVING
> - UNION or UNION ALL
> - Subquery in the select list
> - Certain joins (see additional join discussion later in this section)
> - Reference to nonupdatable view in the FROM clause
> - Subquery in the WHERE clause that refers to a table in the FROM clause
> - Refers only to literal values (in this case, there is no underlying table to update)
> - ALGORITHM = TEMPTABLE (use of a temporary table always makes a view nonupdatable)
> - Multiple references to any column of a base table

Read more about it in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html).